# Retrieve data under userids from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing a problem on how to retrieve all data under uids to list string.But I don't know how to pass uids.

[image: Here is the sample database structure.The red one is the uid of each user.The green one is the random push key.]
**Edit**
I want to retrieve all data ..I mean there can have many uids and their childs.I want to access all uid(not only my uid but also other uids under mdg node). Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Create a global `ArrayList` in your `Activity`

```
private ArrayList<User> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You need Model class for storing all data.

```
class User {

    private String postText, uploadTime , Uplaoder;


    public User(String postText, String uploadTime, String uplaoder) {
        this.postText = postText;
        this.uploadTime = uploadTime;
        Uplaoder = uplaoder;
    }

    //getter setter here..

}
```

Then in your `Activity`

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("msg");

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshotMessages : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : snapshotMessages.getChildren()) {

                    String post_text = snapshot.child("post_text").getValue(String.class);
                    String upload_time = snapshot.child("upload_time").getValue(String.class);
                    String uploader_name = snapshot.child("uploader_name").getValue(String.class);

                    User user = new User(post_text, upload_time, uploader_name);

                    arrayList.add(user);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I want to retrieve all data ..I mean there can have many uids and their childs.I want to access all uid(not only ny uid but also other uids under mdg node). Please help me...

Comment: updated code. it will fetch  all data now. *Hopefully*